# How to get PHP to download a video file using youtube-dl in a LAMP environment?

Tags: lamp, system-calls, raspbian, youtube-dl

I want to download a video by putting its URL in an input field and have a system call performed to use youtube-dl.

The call itself works, and i do get some response from youtube-dl:

```
[youtube] Setting language 
[youtube] gvdf5n-zI14: Downloading video webpage 
[youtube] gvdf5n-zI14: Downloading video info webpage 
[youtube] gvdf5n-zI14: Extracting video information 
[youtube] gvdf5n-zI14: Extracting video information
```

And that's it; no actual file is to be found on the download location. If, however, I use the same program through SSH, youtube-dl doesn't stop at this stage and leaves a video file as desired, which has said response appended with:

```
[download] Destination: nope_avi-gvdf5n-zI14.mp4
[download] 100.0% of 1.31M at    4.12M/s ETA 00:00
```

How do I get my web server to actually download the video file?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, an error occured. Make sure to capture [stderr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29) as well, for example by adding `2>&1` to the command line, or using [`proc_open`](http://php.net/proc_open).